# JEST Matcher error: received value must be a mock function

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I am receiving "Matcher error: received value must be a mock function" trying to compare the result of the completed function. I do have 1 mock statement that mocks 2 methods from the utilities module for the index module to complete successfully when referencing those. I assume, though, that I do not need to mock index modules in order to pass the test. Here's the whole test that's not working:

```
import * as index from '../src/index';

jest.mock('../src/utils', () => {
  const originalModule = jest.requireActual('../src/utils');

  return {
    __esModule: true,
    ...originalModule,
    downloadModule: jest.fn(() => 'downloaded'),
    compareChecksum: jest.fn(() => true)
  }
});

describe('testing ingex file', () => {
  test('testing case with mocked functions', async () => {
    await expect(index.execute()).resolves.toHaveReturnedWith(undefined);
  });
});
```

Utils is just a file with series of useful methods used in index. While the function called in index looks like this (Redacted):

```
//src/index
export async function execute() {
  switch(type) { // comes from env vars
    case 'file': {
      await downloadModule(params); // mocked to succeed
      if (await compareChecksum(otherParams)) {// mocked to succeed
        console.log("Equal");
        return;
      }
      ...
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

The complete error I am getting:

```
expect(received).resolves.toHaveReturnedWith(expected)

Matcher error: received value must be a mock function

Received has value: undefined
```

So index module is dependent on utils and I mocked all necessary methods for it to pass successfully. Received value just cannot be a mock function ever, and it does receive the "undefined" result as expected but refuses to compare it properly. Not sure why the expected result is supposed to be a mock function in this case.

In case it matters this is typescript (not clearly visible from the code provided) and ts-jest is installed.

Comment: [`toHaveReturnedWith`](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tohavereturnedwithvalue) is an assertion specifically for mock functions, it makes no sense in your case (and to be honest not all that often when you _are_ using a mock function). Don't you just want `expect(index.execute()).resolves.toBeUndefined()`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe you're right, I missed that bit in the documentation.. Worked as expected with the `toBeUndefined`. Could you post your comment as answer so that I can accept it?